# Using $.fn.extend() vs simple assignment

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have seen the following two ways to define a jQuery function:

```
$.fn.myFunc = function () {
  return this.css("color", "red");
}

$.fn.extend({
  myFunc: function () {
    return this.css("color", "red");
  }
});
```

Is there a difference between the two?
Is one more preferable than the other?

Comment: Basically the same and it's just a matter of personal preference